# how to restart , reload or refresh an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, reload, restart

i have sound recorder activity that follows these three steps when you load the Activity:

`Record(1)`➡`stopRecord(2)`➡`playRecordedFile(3)`

- by pressing `(1)` the `(2)` will enable and `(1)` will disable.
- by pressing `(2)` the `(3)`will enable
  and `(2)` will disable.

now i want to restart this wheel, how can i do it? i need `(4)` button that says `Record again?`

```
What is the best way?
What is the simple way?
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe (4) StopRecordedFile and u dont store it, and record one more time...

Comment: you cool but i am looking for the best way to restart an activity to activate first button again